# Ruby, unable to delete file on windows - I suspect encoding problem

Tags: ruby, windows, encoding

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891413/ruby-incompatible-character-encodings-utf-8-and-cp852-encodingcompatibility) - now I can create file "Austra Skujytė.txt" but I am unable to delete it. I suspect that it is caused by ė as other files with fancy characters are also affected. AFAIK there is no way to specify encoding like in file opening:

```
out=File.open("#{file}", "a:UTF-8")
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

To delete the file, try using the short 8.3 filename; e.g.,

```
File.delete("AUSTRA~1.TXT")
```

You can convert a long filename to the short format using FFI:

https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Windows-Examples#wiki-intermediate

It's a bit hacky, but it may be what you need.