# Sass Encoding::CompatibilityError

Tags: ruby, encoding, sass, compatibility

Recently I wanted to start writing code in sass and start using compass. I installed ruby 2.0.0 and after I installed gems etc. I have this error when I try to watch files.

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: CP852 and UTF-8
```

Do you have any advices?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and changed the root directory name now everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an encoding issue. Your SASS files have different encoding from your ruby files.  Try to use a decent editor that supports UTF-8 and avoid pasting stuff in your SASS files and convert any existing files to UTF-8.

If, however, you need to be using this encoding in your external files you need to tell Ruby that these files are using this encoding (as by default it assumes UTF-8). See this SO question as well [Ruby, "incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and CP852 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891413/ruby-incompatible-character-encodings-utf-8-and-cp852-encodingcompatibilit)

Comment: I have never used ruby before. So I read that I have to add this as argument ":encoding => "utf-8"". Maybe this isn't good question, but how I should do it? I trying to deal with this problem from few days. I read tons of websites about it, but I didn't get any progress. Thanks for reply!